# vstest.console code coverage is not including tested project

Tags: c++, code-coverage

I have visual studio solution. It contains 4 projects.

1. Main project (tested project), built as .lib
2. Wrapper project that contains just main and runs Main project, built as .exe
3. Google Test project which builds google test library, buit as .lib
4. UnitTest project that uses 3. and 1., built as .exe

I am using GoogleTestAdapter so my unit test from project 4. are available through visual studio's test explorer and I can test my project just fine.

The problem is that when i run code coverage using Microsoft's code coverage tool I am not getting any coverage results for my Main project. I can only see code coverage for Google Test project (3.) which is weird since both Main project and Google Test project are set up the same way.

Classes from my Main project are not present in code coverage report. I can only see them there if I actually write some tests for that classes and even then code coverage for that classes is 0%.